# Compile-time wildcards in cmake install targets

Tags: cmake

I'm new to cmake and I'm finding it very frustrating. I am trying to use wildcards in file paths that are evaluated when the build runs, not when the build is generated.

I have created a build that uses SWIG to generate Java wrappers for some C++ code. I can write the commands to generate the native code, compile it, and produce a working shared library, and even use the INSTALL command to install that shared library correctly. What I can't figure out how to do is to write an INSTALL command that can copy all *.java files generated by SWIG into that same install location.

It seems that cmake's FILE GLOB command does the globbing when cmake is executed, and not when the build actually runs. Of course, when cmake is executed, SWIG hasn't run yet, and the Java files don't exist.

Is there a way to do what I want? Am I going about things wrong? It seems like this is such a fundamental part of what Makefiles need to do, I'm really surprised not to find an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that the Java wrappers are located in the current binary directory, you can use the following `install` command to copy the Java files upon install:

```
install(
    CODE "file( GLOB _GeneratedJavaSources \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*.java\" )"
    CODE "file( INSTALL \${_GeneratedJavaSources} DESTINATION \"$ENV{HOME}\" )"
)
```

The `CODE` form of the `install` command is used to execute two CMake commands upon running the install target. The first one collects all generated Java files in a helper variable. The second one uses the `INSTALL` form of the `file` command to copy the files.

Comment: I have trouble using this: if executable permission is not copied over. Installing programs this way makes the program non-runnable. Any way to install while preserving permissions?

Comment: Ah, fixed, I needed to use `COPY` instead of `INSTALL`. Strange that `INSTALL` removes permissions by default... See here, search for INSTALL: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use install(SCRIPT swigInstaller.cmake) or install(DIRECTORY) both of which supports doing file globing at install time. You can read more about the install command at:

http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:install

Comment: Boy, this is so close. "SCRIPT" doesn't seem to help, since INSTALL can't be included in such a script, apparently; but INSTALL(DIRECTORY) is extremely close. The only thing is that it insists on copying all the directory trees from the source directory, even though they all end up empty. Any way to prune them, or make INSTALL(DIRECTORY) only consider files directly in the source directory?