# CMake Error: TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target

Tags: cmake, lemon-graph-library

When building an opensource project with CMake (in my case, it was the lemon graph library), I got this error when I tried to build shared libaries via `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1`:

```
TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target
```

Where does this error come from and how do I fix it?

Comment: I got the same problem and fixed it just by adding the [`include(GNUInstallDirs)`](https://github.com/risoflora/libsagui/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L73).

Answer (score 44):

In my `CMakeLists.txt`, my INSTALL command had no LIBRARY parameter.

Changing from this:

```
INSTALL(
  TARGETS lemon
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  COMPONENT library
)
```

to this:

```
INSTALL(
  TARGETS lemon
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib  # <-- Add this line
  COMPONENT library
)
```

fixed my problem.

Answer (score 17):

I got this... Another reason this happens is when you create a shared library

add_library(${NAME} SHARED sources )

then when Cmake reaches the install command on Windows platform, it complains of these error, solution is to use RUNTIME instead of LIBRARY, like

```
if(WIN32)
  install(TARGETS ${NAME}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION path)
else()
  install(TARGETS ${NAME}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION path)
endif()
```

Comment: Are the two usages of `path` in your example different? If not you can achieve the same effect with

    `install(TARGETS ${NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION path
        LIBRARY DESTINATION path
    )`

Answer (score 5):

After `DESTINATION`, it should have `bin`, `lib`, `include`.

install `lib` or `bin`

```
install(TARGETS snappy
        EXPORT SnappyTargets
        # RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR} # DESTINATION error
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR} # should add bin or other dir
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        # ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR # DESTINATION error
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} # should add lib
)
```

For example, install `.h` file:

```
install(
        FILES
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_hard1.h"
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h"
        # DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} #  error install FILES given no DESTINATION!

        # add include after DESTINATION, then it works
        DESTINATION include ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)
```

see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html for more detail:

```
install(TARGETS myExe mySharedLib myStaticLib
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static)
install(TARGETS mySharedLib DESTINATION /some/full/path)
```

Comment: more elegant way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637261/compile-time-wildcards-in-cmake-install-targets

Comment: your issue also might be that ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} is undefined

Answer (score 1):

I just faced a similar problem. As @Fernando said in his answer, you can go with that solution. Another and similar solution is to just `include(GNUInstallDirs)`

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}Config"
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar, but not identical error message:

```
CMake Error at xxx/CMakeLists.txt:123 (install):
  install Library TARGETS given no DESTINATION!
```

The fix in this case was to simply update CMake; from version 3.13.3 to 3.25.1 or really any newer version.

Note: I had originally posted my own question at [CMake Error: install Library TARGETS given no DESTINATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757955/cmake-error-install-library-targets-given-no-destination) but it was closed as a duplicate (although the error message was different), so I posted my own answer here.

I do not know if this would fix the `TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target` error.

The other answers all talk about modifying the CMake configuration files (i.e. CMakeLists.txt), so this answer is new - and easier.

Our fix was just to update, and leave the configuration alone. As the error was thrown from another open source project, this was by far the better fix, for us.

Answer (score 0):

Since CMake 3.14 the option DESTINATION is **no longer required** for executables, shared/static libraries and some other artifacts: CMake provides reasonable defaults for their installation directories. Alternatively, one could include module [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/GNUInstallDirs.html), and set corresponding `CMAKE_INSTALL_<dir>` variable.

> For regular executables, static libraries and shared libraries, the `DESTINATION` argument is not required. For these target types, when `DESTINATION` is omitted, a default destination will be taken from the appropriate variable from `GNUInstallDirs`, or set to a built-in default value if that variable is not defined. The same is true for the public and private headers associated with the installed targets through the `PUBLIC_HEADER` and `PRIVATE_HEADER` target properties.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/install.html#targets