# How to build Openscenegraph earth 2.6

Tags: c++, build, cmake, openscenegraph

sorry for my bad english..

I'm trying to get osgEarth working with c++ and visual studio 2013.

I first downloaded Open Scene Graph 3.2 and the prebuild dependencies (small package) from this page. I generated the visual studio 2013 project and build/installed Open Scene Graph without much problem.

After that, I downloaded the source of osgearth 2.6 and when I try to create visual studio solution I have some kinds of error:

```
    Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:616 (message):
  c:/lib/Qt/5.3.2/5.3/msvc2013_opengl/bin/qmake.exe reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS
  as "C:/lib/Qt/5.3.2/5.3/msvc2013_opengl/lib" but QtCore could not be found
  there.  Qt is NOT installed correctly for the target build environment.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:147 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/ModuleInstall.cmake:57 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgEarth".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarth/CMakeLists.txt:304 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/ModuleInstall.cmake:57 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgEarthAnnotation".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthAnnotation/CMakeLists.txt:89 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/ModuleInstall.cmake:57 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgEarthFeatures".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthFeatures/CMakeLists.txt:117 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/ModuleInstall.cmake:57 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgEarthUtil".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthUtil/CMakeLists.txt:185 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/ModuleInstall.cmake:57 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgEarthSymbology".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthSymbology/CMakeLists.txt:122 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_earth".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/earth/CMakeLists.txt:28 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_kml".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/kml/CMakeLists.txt:92 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_wcs".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/wcs/CMakeLists.txt:26 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_wms".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/wms/CMakeLists.txt:13 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_tilecache".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/tilecache/CMakeLists.txt:9 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_tileservice".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/tileservice/CMakeLists.txt:8 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_yahoo".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/yahoo/CMakeLists.txt:3 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_arcgis_map_cache".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/arcgis_map_cache/CMakeLists.txt:2 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_arcgis".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/arcgis/CMakeLists.txt:14 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_tms".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/tms/CMakeLists.txt:12 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_vpb".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/vpb/CMakeLists.txt:9 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_osg".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/osg/CMakeLists.txt:7 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_agglite".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/agglite/CMakeLists.txt:11 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_model_simple".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/model_simple/CMakeLists.txt:4 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_debug".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/debug/CMakeLists.txt:4 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_cache_filesystem".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/cache_filesystem/CMakeLists.txt:12 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_refresh".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/refresh/CMakeLists.txt:8 (SETUP_PLUGIN)


CMake Error at CMakeModules/OsgEarthMacroUtils.cmake:231 (INSTALL):
  install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "osgdb_osgearth_xyz".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/osgEarthDrivers/xyz/CMakeLists.txt:10 (SETUP_PLUGIN)
...
ZLIB_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "osgEarth" in directory C:/Users/***/Desktop/OSG/osgearth-osgearth-2.6/src/osgEarth

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Dario/Desktop/OSG/TempBuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Dario/Desktop/OSG/TempBuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have used the same prebuild dependencies package that works fine with Osg..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the Qt bit you can ignore if you're not trying to build with Qt.

I think osgEarth pretty much needs ZLIB, or at least, I've always built with it.

Make sure your ZLIB entries in CMake are found ok:

Mine look like 
ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR C:/blah/blah/windows-VS10.0.30319-x86-release/include
ZLIB_LIBRARY C:/blah/blah/windows-VS10.0.30319-x86-release/lib/zlib.lib

See if that resolves some of the problems. I'm not familiar with the install targets error, but googling suggests:
[CMake Error: TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990343/cmake-error-targets-given-no-library-destination-for-shared-library-target)

that it might be a busted CMake file. Make sure you are using the HEAD release of osgEarth 2.6 in case there were bug fixes after the 2.6 tagged release.