# Android NDK install TARGETS given no RUNTIME DESTINATION for executable target

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to import an external C/C++ library in my android module in one of the projects. The library is called [android-fluidsynth](https://github.com/VolcanoMobile/fluidsynth-android). I am following instructions given at [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake.html#include-other-cmake-projects) to integrate it. Following is how my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

**EDIT 2** :  The below one works

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build your native library.
# This ensures that a certain set of CMake features is available to
# your build.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


######################################################################################
######### Adding fluidsynth library from the external code
######################################################################################
# Sets lib_src_DIR to the path of the target CMake project.
set(fluidsynth-lib-name libfluidsynthsrc)
set( lib_DIR /Users/swapnilgupta/work/musicmuni/fluidsynth-android/android/ )

# Sets lib_build_DIR to the path of the desired output directory.
set( lib_build_DIR ${lib_DIR}/outputs )
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${lib_build_DIR})

# Adds the CMakeLists.txt file located in the specified directory
# as a build dependency.
add_subdirectory( # Specifies the directory of the CMakeLists.txt file.
                  ${lib_DIR}

                  # Specifies the directory for the build outputs.
                  ${lib_build_DIR} )

# Adds the output of the additional CMake build as a prebuilt static
# library and names it.
add_library( ${fluidsynth-lib-name}
                SHARED
                IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( ${fluidsynth-lib-name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${lib_build_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib${fluidsynth-lib-name}.so )
```

<s>On trying to build this I get the following error:</s>

```
install TARGETS given no RUNTIME DESTINATION for executable target   "fluidsynth"
```

I have gone through some SO posts and added following lines in my `CMakeLists.txt` but I still get this error.

```
if(WIN32)
  install(TARGETS fluidsynth
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ./)
else()
  install(TARGETS fluidsynth
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ./)
endif()
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The error message seems to be clear: `fluidsynth` is an executable target, thus it requires *RUNTIME DESTINATION*. But your code sets *LIBRARY DESTINATION* for non-Windows platforms. BTW, the code you show doesn't contains creation of `fluidsynth` target, it creates only `libfluidsynth` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to invent your own `CMakeLists.txt` for **libfluidsynth**. You can point your **externalNativeBuild** to `fluidsynth-android-1.1.10/android/CMakeLists.txt`.

This defines the **fluidsynth** library that you can use as dependency for other libraries, e.g.

```
target_link_libraries(<mylibname> fluidsynth log)
```

Comment: I tried that but it still shows error in one of the `install` statements. Also, when I try to run `cmake CMakeLists` after going to the directory where I have the source code sitting i.e. `<path>/fluidsynth-android-1.1.10/src`, I get the following error `install TARGETS given no RUNTIME DESTINATION for executable target
  "fluidsynth".`  I have used the following `https://stackoverflow.com/a/35756700/2606411` instructions in being able to build it but don't know how to incorporate in my android library.

Comment: Not <path>/fluidsynth-android-1.1.10/src, but <path>/fluidsynth-android-1.1.10/android

Comment: One more question @Alex, if I have mentioned name `libfluidsynthsrc` in my `add_library(...)` method, using `set_target_properties( ${fluidsynth-lib-name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${lib_build_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib${fluidsynth-lib-name}.so )` is correct or I should not use a prefix `lib` before the librry name?

**FYI** I had use a custom CMakeLists.txt because I want to link this library with another library that I am creating internally!

Comment: If you build libfluidsynth with fluidsynth-android-1.1.10/android/CMakeLists.txt, you can use it as a dependency for your library, don't need to declare it as IMPORTED. Chaining CMakeLists.txt files is easy, they have the `add_subdirectory` command for that.

Comment: You mean that I don't have to use `add_library()` and `set_target_properties()` for fluidsynth-android-1.1.10? If not, then how would I try to link it to my library. Right now, I was trying to use `target_link_libraries(<mylibname>
                        ${fluidsynth-lib-name}
                        log)` to build my library with fluidsynth.

Comment: Btw... I used the following instructions to do what I am doing right now https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake.html#include-other-cmake-projects

Comment: You will `target_link_libraries(<mylibname> fluidsynth log)` instead

Comment: And I don't have to use add_library() and set_target_properties() for fluidsynth-android-1.1.10 ... Right ?

Comment: The project that you use already did add_library(fluidsynth) for you

Comment: Ohh okay... Got it ... Thanks ☺

Comment: For building fluidsynth from the volcanomobiles repo, I tried building it by downloading one of its releases(https://github.com/VolcanoMobile/fluidsynth-android/releases). The release bundle does not seem to have an `android` folder. When I directly check out the entire repo and build it, I have some issues while running it. Can you please give some pointers on how to have it run by using a release bundle?

Comment: the 'release' was not taken from branch, that's why you see the difference. I guess you should [open an Issue](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/issues/new) on GitHub if you something does not work for you.

Comment: fast rendering of file is not working for me. I have discussed this on the `fluid-dev` mailing list and it seems that the VolcanoMobile/fluidsynth-android seems to have some components missing from the original fluidsynth code. I did check the CMakeLists.txt and it seems that they have excluded a major portion of code in the fork. Now, VolcanoMobile/fluidsynth-android does not have a page to open an issue so I am kind of stuck. I am unable to contact [Philippe Simons](https://github.com/loki666) who made these changes.

Comment: Btw... @Alex I have been trying fast rendering of MIDI and soundfonts into a raw PCM file. Do you know of any other libraries that can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

One minor: the `set(runtime_destination)` statement has no effect, you can remove it.

The other is likely what trips up your build: `DYNAMIC` is not a valid CMake library type, AFAIK. You should change it to `SHARED`.

Then, since it's an imported target, you will need to specify its location, by adding something along the lines of:

```
set_target_property(TARGET ${fluidsynth-lib-name} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION path-to-libfluidsynth.so)
```

Comment: HEY @Nicolas thank you for your response . Sorry.. I was in middle of editing and that's why that 'runtime_destination' statement and I already have a set_target_properties statement in place.