# CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt: No cmake_minimum_required command is present. A line of code such as cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

Tags: visual-c++, ssh, cmake, sftp, libssh

I'm trying to build ssh.lib from source using cmake.

For this purpose I have downloaded the libssh 0.8.2, Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_1_0i and cmake-3.9.0-rc1-win64-x64.

Visual Studio 2017 is used. I have installed open SSL into c directory then I use cmake assign the source and build paths. While generating, it showing error "Error in the configuration process, Project files may be invalid" and

```
**CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:335 (install):
  install Library TARGETS given no DESTINATION!


Threads_FOUND=
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.**
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14990343/10330249) , still, the issue is not solved. I'm trying to do this from many days, any suggestions or help, please.

and C:\Users\Sami\Downloads\libssh-0.8.0.tar\libssh-0.8.0\src\CMakeLists.txt is below 
**

```
set(LIBSSH_PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIRS
  ${libssh_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  CACHE INTERNAL "libssh public include directories"
)

set(LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
  ${libssh_BINARY_DIR}
)

set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
  ${LIBSSH_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES}
)

if (WIN32)
  set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
    ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES}
    ws2_32
  )
endif (WIN32)

if (HAVE_LIBSOCKET)
  set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
    ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES}
    socket
  )
endif (HAVE_LIBSOCKET)

if (OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY)
  set(LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
  )

  set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
    ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES}
    ${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY}
  )
endif (OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY)

if (MBEDTLS_CRYPTO_LIBRARY)
    set(LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
      ${LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
      ${MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )
  set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
    ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES}
    ${MBEDTLS_CRYPTO_LIBRARY}
  )
endif (MBEDTLS_CRYPTO_LIBRARY)

if (GCRYPT_LIBRARY)
  set(LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GCRYPT_INCLUDE_DIR}
  )

  set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
    ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES}
    ${GCRYPT_LIBRARY}
  )
endif (GCRYPT_LIBRARY)

if (WITH_ZLIB)
  set(LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}
  )

  set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
    ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES}
    ${ZLIB_LIBRARY}
  )
endif (WITH_ZLIB)

if (WITH_GSSAPI AND GSSAPI_FOUND)
  set(LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GSSAPI_INCLUDE_DIR}
  )

  set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
    ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES}
    ${GSSAPI_LIBRARIES}
  )
endif (WITH_GSSAPI AND GSSAPI_FOUND)

if (WITH_NACL AND NACL_FOUND)
  set(LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${NACL_INCLUDE_DIR}
  )

  set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
    ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES}
    ${NACL_LIBRARY}
  )
endif (WITH_NACL AND NACL_FOUND)

set(LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES
  ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES}
  CACHE INTERNAL "libssh link libraries"
)

set(LIBSSH_SHARED_LIBRARY
  ssh_shared
  CACHE INTERNAL "libssh shared library"
)

if (WITH_STATIC_LIB)
  set(LIBSSH_STATIC_LIBRARY
    ssh_static
    CACHE INTERNAL "libssh static library"
  )
endif (WITH_STATIC_LIB)

set(libssh_SRCS
  agent.c
  auth.c
  base64.c
  bignum.c
  buffer.c
  callbacks.c
  channels.c
  client.c
  config.c
  connect.c
  connector.c
  curve25519.c
  dh.c
  ecdh.c
  error.c
  getpass.c
  init.c
  kex.c
  known_hosts.c
  knownhosts.c
  legacy.c
  log.c
  match.c
  messages.c
  misc.c
  options.c
  packet.c
  packet_cb.c
  packet_crypt.c
  pcap.c
  pki.c
  pki_container_openssh.c
  pki_ed25519.c
  poll.c
  session.c
  scp.c
  socket.c
  string.c
  threads.c
  wrapper.c
  external/bcrypt_pbkdf.c
  external/blowfish.c
  external/chacha.c
  external/ed25519.c
  external/fe25519.c
  external/ge25519.c
  external/poly1305.c
  external/sc25519.c
  chachapoly.c
)

if (CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT)
    set(libssh_SRCS
        ${libssh_SRCS}
        threads/noop.c
        threads/pthread.c
    )
elseif (CMAKE_USE_WIN32_THREADS_INIT)
        set(libssh_SRCS
            ${libssh_SRCS}
            threads/noop.c
            threads/winlocks.c
        )
else()
    set(libssh_SRCS
        ${libssh_SRCS}
        threads/noop.c
    )
endif()

if (WITH_GCRYPT)
    set(libssh_SRCS
        ${libssh_SRCS}
        threads/libgcrypt.c
        libgcrypt.c
        gcrypt_missing.c
        pki_gcrypt.c
        ecdh_gcrypt.c
       )
elseif (WITH_MBEDTLS)
    set(libssh_SRCS
        ${libssh_SRCS}
        threads/mbedtls.c
        libmbedcrypto.c
        mbedcrypto_missing.c
        pki_mbedcrypto.c
        ecdh_mbedcrypto.c
       )
else (WITH_GCRYPT)
    set(libssh_SRCS
        ${libssh_SRCS}
        threads/libcrypto.c
        pki_crypto.c
        ecdh_crypto.c
        libcrypto.c
       )
    if(OPENSSL_VERSION VERSION_LESS "1.1.0")
        set(libssh_SRCS ${libssh_SRCS} libcrypto-compat.c)
    endif()
endif (WITH_GCRYPT)

if (WITH_SFTP)
  set(libssh_SRCS
    ${libssh_SRCS}
    sftp.c
  )

  if (WITH_SERVER)
    set(libssh_SRCS
      ${libssh_SRCS}
      sftpserver.c
    )
  endif (WITH_SERVER)
endif (WITH_SFTP)

if (WITH_SERVER)
  set(libssh_SRCS
    ${libssh_SRCS}
    server.c
    bind.c
  )
endif (WITH_SERVER)

if (WITH_ZLIB)
  set(libssh_SRCS
    ${libssh_SRCS}
    gzip.c
  )
endif(WITH_ZLIB)

if (WITH_GSSAPI AND GSSAPI_FOUND)
  set(libssh_SRCS
    ${libssh_SRCS}
    gssapi.c
  )
endif (WITH_GSSAPI AND GSSAPI_FOUND)

if (NOT WITH_NACL)
  set(libssh_SRCS
    ${libssh_SRCS}
    external/curve25519_ref.c
  )
endif (NOT WITH_NACL)

include_directories(
  ${LIBSSH_PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${LIBSSH_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# Set the path to the default map file
set(MAP_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map")

if (WITH_SYMBOL_VERSIONING AND ABIMAP_FOUND)
    # Get the list of header files
    get_file_list("dev_header_list"
                  DIRECTORIES "${LIBSSH_PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIRS}/libssh"
                  FILES_PATTERNS "*.h")

    # Extract the symbols marked as "LIBSSH_API" from the header files
    extract_symbols("${PROJECT_NAME}_dev.symbols"
                    HEADERS_LIST_FILE "dev_header_list"
                    FILTER_PATTERN "LIBSSH_API")

    if (WITH_ABI_BREAK)
        set(ALLOW_ABI_BREAK "BREAK_ABI")
    endif()

    # Generate the symbol version map file
    generate_map_file("${PROJECT_NAME}_dev.map"
                      SYMBOLS "${PROJECT_NAME}_dev.symbols"
                      RELEASE_NAME_VERSION ${PROJECT_NAME}_AFTER_${LIBRARY_VERSION}
                      CURRENT_MAP ${MAP_PATH}
                      ${ALLOW_ABI_BREAK})

    set(libssh_SRCS
      ${libssh_SRCS}
      ${PROJECT_NAME}_dev.map
    )
endif (WITH_SYMBOL_VERSIONING AND ABIMAP_FOUND)

add_library(${LIBSSH_SHARED_LIBRARY} SHARED ${libssh_SRCS})

target_link_libraries(${LIBSSH_SHARED_LIBRARY} ${LIBSSH_LINK_LIBRARIES})

if (WITH_SYMBOL_VERSIONING)
    if (ABIMAP_FOUND)
        # Change path to devel map file
        set(MAP_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_dev.map")
    endif (ABIMAP_FOUND)

    set_target_properties(${LIBSSH_SHARED_LIBRARY}
                          PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS
                          "-Wl,--version-script,\"${MAP_PATH}\"")
endif (WITH_SYMBOL_VERSIONING)

set_target_properties(
  ${LIBSSH_SHARED_LIBRARY}
    PROPERTIES
      VERSION
        ${LIBRARY_VERSION}
      SOVERSION
        ${LIBRARY_SOVERSION}
      OUTPUT_NAME
        ssh
      DEFINE_SYMBOL
        LIBSSH_EXPORTS
)

if (WITH_VISIBILITY_HIDDEN)
  set_target_properties(${LIBSSH_SHARED_LIBRARY} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-fvisibility=hidden")
endif (WITH_VISIBILITY_HIDDEN)

if (MINGW)
    set_target_properties(${LIBSSH_SHARED_LIBRARY} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup")
endif ()


install(
  TARGETS
    ${LIBSSH_SHARED_LIBRARY}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${BIN_INSTALL_DIR}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
  COMPONENT libraries
)

if (WITH_STATIC_LIB)
  add_library(${LIBSSH_STATIC_LIBRARY} STATIC ${libssh_SRCS})

  if (MSVC)
    set(OUTPUT_SUFFIX static)
  else (MSVC)
    set(OUTPUT_SUFFIX )
  endif (MSVC)
  set_target_properties(
    ${LIBSSH_STATIC_LIBRARY}
      PROPERTIES
        VERSION
          ${LIBRARY_VERSION}
        SOVERSION
          ${LIBRARY_SOVERSION}
        OUTPUT_NAME
          ssh
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_SUFFIX}
  )

  if (WIN32)
    set_target_properties(
      ${LIBSSH_STATIC_LIBRARY}
        PROPERTIES
          COMPILE_FLAGS
            "-DLIBSSH_STATIC"
    )
  endif (WIN32)

  install(
    TARGETS
      ${LIBSSH_STATIC_LIBRARY}
    DESTINATION
      ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/${OUTPUT_SUFFIX}
    COMPONENT
      libraries
  )
endif (WITH_STATIC_LIB)

message(STATUS "Threads_FOUND=${Threads_FOUND}")
```

**

Comment: To me it looks like you are using the wrong CMakeLists.txt file. Does the top level directory of libssh `C:\Users\Sami\Downloads\libssh-0.8.0.tar\libssh-0.8.0\` contains a CMakeLists.txt? If so, use that one.

Comment: Excellent. Helped me in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `CMakeLists.txt:335` edit as below

```
INSTALL(
TARGETS ${LIBSSH_SHARD_LIBRARY}
 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin $(BIN_INSTALL_DIR)
 LIBRARY DESTINATION lib $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)
 ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib $(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)
 COMPONENT libraries
)
```

And top of `CMakeList.txt` add below line

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 7):

The warning

```
No cmake_minimum_required command is present.
```

usually signals that **wrong source directory** is used, and `CMakeLists.txt` in this directory isn't supposed to be a top-level one during the configuration.

In the given case, you use `src/` subdirectory as a source, but the correct way is to use the upper one, `C:\Users\Sami\Downloads\libssh-0.8.0.tar\libssh-0.8.0`.

Proper top-level `CMakeLists.txt` contains `cmake_minimum_required` call and defines all variables needed for `CMakeLists.txt` in the subdirectories.