# CMake install(CODE ...) unexpected behavior

Tags: bash, cmake

I have the following lines in my CMakeLists.txt :

```
set(MY_COMMAND "cp /absolute/path/*.so /other/absolute/path")
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${MY_COMMAND})")
```

It returns the following error :

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/absolute/path/*.so’: No such file or directory
```

When I specify a lib :

```
set(MY_COMMAND "cp /absolute/path/somelib.so /other/absolute/path")
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${MY_COMMAND})")
```

It works.

When I run the first command from the terminal :

```
cp /absolute/path/*.so /other/absolute/path
```

It also works.

Any idea ?

Comment: On Stack Overflow we tend to **not mix problems and solutions** in the question post. If you found a solution to your problem, you may post your answer, and describe the solution in it. *Answering your own questions is  perfectly valid*. Please, move description under `EDIT` clause into your own answer post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a wildcard expression command in terminal, the wildcard expansion happens within the terminal itself and not by `cp`.

However, when it's done from CMake there is apparently no expansion of the wildcard. Therefore, you need to obtain the file list first and then run the command you want using the obtained file list.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5649382/1280800) for the example.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested dreamzor, I finally came to the following solution :

```
install(CODE "file(GLOB MY_LIBS \"/absolute/path/*.so\")"
        CODE "file(INSTALL \${MY_LIBS} DESTINATION \"/other/absolute/path\")")
```